# How to get the serial no of a computer in network based on hostname of a machine ?

Tags: c#, javascript, vbscript, network-programming

```
ComputerName = InputBox("Enter the name of the computer you wish to query")

winmgmt1 = "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!//"& ComputerName &""

'WScript.Echo winmgmt1

Set SNSet = GetObject( winmgmt1 ).InstancesOf ("Win32_BIOS")

for each SN in SNSet
MsgBox "The serial number for the specified computer is: " & SN.SerialNumber
Next
```

From this i am able to get Serial no of my machine But what to do to get the serial no of other computers in the network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that:

- (Windows) Firewall / DCOM settings on the remote computer does not block your requests
- that you have credentials for the remote computer

More information and code samples can be found on the MSDN site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx